# Using R scripts with sextante processing framework?

Tags: qgis, r, sextante

I want to use R scripts from the module Sextante treatment QGIS , but I have many difficulties to configure the module in Sextante . Following the procedure described in the official documentation of QGIS. I get the following error message :

```
"Missing dependency.This algorithm can not be run :-(
This algorithm Requires R to be run.Unfortunately , It Seems That R is not installed in your system , or it is not Correctly configured to be used from QGIS
Click here to know more about how to install and configure R to be used with QGIS "
```

I have completed all prerequisites needed to run the scripts:

1. R is installed on my machine
2. Sextante module and third party applications have been installed and configured. All other third-party applications work well : Saga , OTB , Grass , except R . See attachment[image].

I suspect an error in the path to the binary directory and scripts. Otherwise I do not see any track.

I use QGIS 2.2 from OSGeo4W stacked version on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm trying to use R on Qgis and I'm having the same problem. I'v seen that you posted this question about 7 months ago, so were you able to fix it? It would be a great help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the R folder path to something like this:

C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\

instead of pointing to the bin folder. I just checked it on QGIS 2.8.1 and it works.